# Selecting a specific formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to get a cell to implement a specific formula based on the contents of another cell.

For example, if one cell contains "general" then a generic sum formula is applied to the cell, though if it contains "conditional" then a countif formula is applied. I can't do this through a general series of chained if statements as there are around 500 formulas that constantly get added and amended and the formula entry area is insufficient to hold them all.

Comment: How about [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/VLOOKUP-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65)? You create a table of key-value pairs, where the key is the condition (i.e. "general") and the corresponding value is the formula you want to apply. You might have to do some cell gymnastics to get all the references right.

Comment: I would create a Sub to start processing these cells, and depending on how complex your 500 formulas are based on, different technique can be used - but not enough information you have shown us.

Comment: The formula's to apply aren't really complex, basic operations and calculations on 2 separate cells. They are currently in a table that I can use a VLOOKUP on, but all that doing that does is populates the cell with the formula, it doesn't execute it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out using a UDF and evaluate.

```
Public Function ev(r As String) As Variant
    Application.Volatile (True)
    ev = Evaluate(Replace(r, "@", Application.Caller.Row))
End Function
```

Put a Vlookup inside the ev() call, and have the formulas with @ replacing all the row references. Not sure if it is the best way but it got it working.